# Get the url to file uploaded by user in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want my users to be able to upload a file in the my contact form and I use contact form 7 like this: [file your-file]

Problem is that iam using a 3 party receiver of the mail that can't accept files (Pardot), so I need to host the image in wordpress and send the URL to the file, not the file itself. Right now I have a plugin(Advanced CF7 DB) to store the image but I need to send the url to that file.

Anyone got an ide on how to achive this?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need some help, but I have the same problem.

I find a clue, looking at the [CF7 doc](https://contactform7.com/file-uploading-and-attachment/) you can get the URL using PHP and add the file name with JavaScript to send data.

```
$upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
echo $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/wpcf7_uploads';
```

Then with JavaScript, get the file name and add it